# Throw exception only in some cases from a list of values in java

Tags: java, list, loops, arraylist, null

I have a list of values which has maximum of four elements.
I need to loop through the list and need to throw exception only in some cases.
The different scenarios where the exception needs to be thrown are as follows.

1. When null value comes in the middle of the list.
   Some examples are:

```
 List<String> values = ["test1","test2",null,"test4"];
 List<String> values = ["test1",null,"test3","test4"];
 List<String> values = ["test1",null,null,"test4"];
```

2. When null value comes in the beginning of the list.
   Some examples are:

```
List<String> values = [null,"test2","test3","test4"];
List<String> values = [null,null,"test3","test4"];
List<String> values = [null,null,null,"test4"];
```

All other cases are valid ones and should not throw exception.
Valid cases are:

```
List<String> values = ["test1","test2","test3","test4"];
List<String> values = ["test1","test2","test3",null];
List<String> values = ["test1","test2",null,null];
List<String> values = ["test1",null,null,null];
List<String> values = [null,null,null,null];
```

Can someone please help on this?

Comment: This is  `List<String> values = ["test1","test2",null,"test4"]`  invalid then how come this is `List<String> values = ["test1","test2",null,null]` valid ? Plus are you having `list` with `size 4` only ?

Comment: When null comes in the middle it is an invalid case in the current scenario that I am working. There will be maximum of 4 elements in the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should ensure no non-null elements are present following a null. Otherwise, you will throw an exception

```
boolean nullSeen = false;
for (String s : list) {
    if (s == null) {
        nullSeen = true;
    } else if (nullSeen) { // for a non-null string
        throw new RuntimeException("Non-null value followed a null");
    }
}
```

For each element, we check if it is *null* and if so, we set the boolean flag, `nullSeen`. And if we encounter a non-null string with `nullSeen` already set to *true*, we throw an exception.

---

If you are using Java 9+ and would prefer a stream based solution, then we can use the [dropWhile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#dropWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-) method.

```
boolean noNonNullValueAfterNull = list.stream()
            .dropWhile(Objects::nonNull) //dropWhile(s -> s != null)
            .allMatch(Objects::isNull); //allMatch(s -> s == null)

if (!noNonNullValueAfterNull) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Non-null value followed a null");
}
```

From the stream created out of the list, it drops the prefix of elements till it sees a *null*. The rest of the elements in the stream must be *null* for the return value to be *true*.

Note: For an empty stream (all nulls), it will return *true* which is what we want as well.

Comment: This is how people with experience code like :O